# Update a document in RavenDB

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, ravendb

I am using asp.net MVC2.

I have a model defined as

```
public class Department
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public object Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Department Name is required")]
        [StringLength(25)]
        [DisplayName("Department Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(true)]
        [DisplayName("Active?")]        
        public bool Active { get; set; }
    }
```

How to update an existing department document through my controller?
my edit action is defined as

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(string id, Department department)
{
..
}
```

answer stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117966/updating-documents-in-ravendb) tells there is a `PATCH` command to update a document.
But i didn't find this in `IDocumentSession` class in Raven's Client API

I do not want to first get the document and then update it like the way it is done in RavenDB's MVCMusicStore example

```
var albumModel = session.Load<Album>(id);
            //Save Album

            UpdateModel(albumModel, "Album");
            session.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use code like this:

```
DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands.Batch(
  new PatchCommandData{
        Key = "users/15",
        Patches = new [] {
            Type = "Set",
            Name = "Email",
            Value = "Ayende"
        }
   }
);
```

See [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/d224b175a066d17b/f07d5b0c59299204) on the discussion group for more info

Comment: Thanks. I also tried with setting the Id which was auto generated by RavenDB and then storing the document dbSession.Store(department). It worked too!