# How to insert update a document in RavenDB Studio (RQL)

Tags: sql, database, ravendb

I have an assigment on ravenDb and I've written queries for selecting, sorting, filtering and such. But I cannot figure out how to do simple adding a new document to a collection named "Employees" or updating a value inside document "employees/8-A", from "employees".

I have gone through the documention using these links:

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.4/csharp/client-api/operations/patching/set-based
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.4/csharp/client-api/operations/patching/single-document

I even googled and came across this thread ; [Updating documents in RavenDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117966/updating-documents-in-ravendb) But one of the linked articles is deleted.

But it's just JS code. Is there no syntax I can run inside the query tool in raven db studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For managing updates from the `Session`,
Look at the following demos:

**Adding/creating a new document:** 
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/basics/create-document 
**Load and edit document:** 
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/basics/load-and-edit-document

---

For updating a field with `Patching`, from all docs, see the **inner RQL** for example here: 
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.4/csharp/client-api/operations/patching/set-based#updating-by-document-id-using-parameters

```
from @all_docs as d
where id() in ($ids)
update { d.Updated = true; }
```

Or, from a **specific collection:**

```
from Companies
update { this.Name = 'newName'; }
```

---

Learn also about **Patching** here: 
https://ravendb.net/learn/inside-ravendb-book/reader/4.0/4-deep-dive-into-the-ravendb-client-api#patching-documents-and-concurrent-modifications